How to duplicate a procedural path with array and curve modifier?
I've created this chain following a tutorial using a path. If I extrude or elongated the path the chain will form which is cool.
My problem is that I cannot duplicate this chain so I can have a second one with the same characteristics. How can I duplicate both path and chain to behave the same way as the original one?


